# Read Encrypted S/Mime E-mail with Outlook OOM or Redemption RDO

Tags: c#, encryption, outlook, outlook-redemption

here's my attempt:

```
Outlook.Application app = new Outlook.Application();
RDOSession session = new RDOSession();
session.MAPIOBJECT = app.Session.MAPIOBJECT;
RDOFolder inbox = session.GetDefaultFolder(rdoDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
RDOItems items = inbox.Items;
RDOMail mail = items.GetFirst();
if (mail.MessageClass == "IPM.Note.SMIME") {
    RDOEncryptedMessage encryptedMessage = (RDOEncryptedMessage)session.GetMessageFromID(mail.EntryID)
    // from here I am stuck because encryptedMessage is null
}
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: solved by installing redemption.dll by regsvr32 instead of the installer

Answer (score 0):

Why do you call `GetMessageFromID` instead of casting mail to `RDOEncryptedMessage`? Are you sure you actually get an encrypted message from `Items.GetFirst`? Do not expect to get the very first message you see in Outlook - you do not sort the Items collection, and most likely `GetFirst` will return the oldest message in the folder, not the topmost message you see in Outlook's explorer.

Comment: I reduced the code exposed here to simplify the issue. In reality, I use `items.MAPITable.Sort` and I got the encrypted mail from a loop with `items.GetNext()`. I am sure the email is encrypted. I see it encrypted in Outlook besides, I checked it has a smime.p7m as attachment. I tried to cast directly like this  `RDOEncryptedMessage encryptedMessage = (RDOEncryptedMessage)mail`, it raises an exception: "Impossible to cast COM object 'System.__ComObject' into RDOEncryptedMessage interface ... This interface is not supported.

Comment: That means Redemption does not see it as the encrypted message. Send an email to redemption at dimastr dot com and i will send you the debug version of Redemption.